# How to build and embed another application inside my target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, build

I have an application in my project (named **App_Main**). And I want to package another tiny application (let's call it **App_Tiny**) inside the package of App_Main.

Then,  as I know App_tiny's path, I can execute App_Tiny programmatically in App_Main's run-time when I need that.

How can I achieve this? How to specify and build another executable target, AND, most importantly, automatically put App_Tiny inside the package directory of App_Main?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For adding a new target it's as easy as hitting the "New Target" button in the left hand pane of your  project explorer. Xcode will allow you to choose the target type (Application) when you add it.

[image: new target button]

Next you need to add FooBarTiny as a build dependancy for your main app (FooBar). Edit the Scheme for your Main Target and add the sub target as an explicit dependancy.

[image]

Now when you build FooBar; FooBarTiny will be built if it needs to be.

Next you add FooBarTiny into the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase. Hit the add button and scroll down the tree and you can find FooBarTiny in the Products folder.

[image]

To launch FooBarTiny from within your app you can use `NSWorkspace`.

`- (NSRunningApplication *)launchApplicationAtURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options configuration:(NSDictionary *)configuration error:(NSError **)error` would probably be a good start point. Check the API docs for other variants.

**EXTRA FOR THE APP STORE**

It's not enough to sign your main app. Any Applescripts and sub-apps (FooBarTiny) will have to be signed as well or your app will fail validation. This answer isn't about that but theres a [good blog on the issue](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/) here.

Comment: I cannot specify the "Main Interface" independently. If I changed the Main Interface of FooBarTiny, FooBar's "Main Interface" change, too. That make one app of them not work.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about but probably means you are trying to use the same file in both targets. Select the file and then press Cmd-alt-1 to bring up the target browser . It will probably be ticked for both your targets under "Target Membership" . Dupe the file and use a unique one for each target

Comment: Please refer to  [this image](http://i39.tinypic.com/1oq7lw.png). This identifies the main menu of the application, right? So, if there is multiple targets, when I change the main menu nib setting of one target among them, other target's setting will be changed, too.

Comment: Yes. Refer to previous comment. You are probably using MainMenu for both targets. Don't.

Comment: Ah, the "Target membership"! Thank you!